how to change the data if the result is not found to 0
> =IFERROR(COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER('MASTER DATA'!Y:Y,
> ('MASTER DATA'!Y:Y <> "") *
> (('MASTER DATA'!M:M = "SURVEY") + ('MASTER DATA'!M:M = "PI")) *
> ('MASTER DATA'!Z:Z >= C4) *
> ('MASTER DATA'!Z:Z <= C5) *  
> ('MASTER DATA'!L:L >= A3) *
> ('MASTER DATA'!L:L <= B3) *  
> ('MASTER DATA'!K:K = "REG") *
> (REGEXMATCH('MASTER DATA'!P:P, "KENDALA IZIN")))
> 0)

how to change the data if the result is not found to 0 ?

    =Let(X,=IFERROR(COUNTUNIQUE(FILTER('MASTER DATA'!Y:Y,
 ('MASTER DATA'!Y:Y <> "") *
 (('MASTER DATA'!M:M = "SURVEY") + ('MASTER DATA'!M:M = "PI")) *
 ('MASTER DATA'!Z:Z >= C4) *
 ('MASTER DATA'!Z:Z <= C5) *  
 ('MASTER DATA'!L:L >= A3) *
 ('MASTER DATA'!L:L <= B3) *  
 ('MASTER DATA'!K:K = "REG") *
 (REGEXMATCH('MASTER DATA'!P:P, "KENDALA IZIN")))
 ""), If(X="",0,X))

